# too many redirects with .htaccess and a very simple configuration

Tags: .htaccess

Good day all.
I'm doing a simple dashboard o a site, I've set up a very simple htaccess to handle some URLs:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#routing:
RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

#errors:
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

As far as I know this should be quite straight forward, but:

going on /page/1234 URL works fine (as well as any other number used, so the pattern is working).

going on www.example.com/login OR www.example.com/login/ is causing:

1) too many redirects error if the "errorDocument" line is on top of everything
2) a /404.php redirect if the "errorDocument" is at the bottom of the htaccess.

while, I can access directly /login.php without any problems.

i've done some tests but I can figure out what is going wrong, I've also tested the file with [this tool](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/):

Comment: Is `login/` a real directory? Try adding `Options -MultiViews` at top of your .htaccess and keep `ErrorDocument 404` line at top.

Comment: no there isn't any directory that could match that.. I'll try the rest now!

Comment: the `Options -MultiViews` does the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comments to answer.

Looks like you have `MultiViews` option turned on and getting this unexpected behavior.

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will try to resolve it and serve `/file.php`.